# How to do IF NOT EXISTS in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to port this line from MS SQL Server to SQLite

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM EVENTTYPE WHERE EventTypeName = 'ANI Received') 
    INSERT INTO EVENTTYPE (EventTypeName) VALUES ('ANI Received');
```

It seems that SQLite does not support IF NOT EXISTS or at least I can't make it work.
Am I missing something simple?  Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

How about this?

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO EVENTTYPE (EventTypeName) VALUES 'ANI Received'
```

(Untested as I don't have SQLite... however [this link](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) is quite descriptive.)

Additionally, this should also work:

```
INSERT INTO EVENTTYPE (EventTypeName)
SELECT 'ANI Received'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM EVENTTYPE WHERE EventTypeName = 'ANI Received');
```

Comment: Thanks.  However, it should be noted that INSERT OR IGNORE piece only works if EventTypeName is set to be unique.

Comment: True.  I assumed that it was unique given how it was used in the sample SQL.  If not, the second method should be used.

Comment: Can the second method really be used if EventTypeName is not unique? I am trying to do something similar and I find that the SELECT WHERE NOT EXISTS clause is returning multiple rows, in fact every row where (the equivalent of )EventTypeName != 'ANI Received' is true.

Comment: The intention is for EventTypeName to be unique. The new value 'ANI Received' is only inserted into table EVENTTYPE if it doesn't already exist in the table.  This is what the WHERE NOT EXISTS comes in.  The SELECT WHERE NOT EXISTS clause can only return a single row; there is not a FROM clause - there is no way multiple rows can be returned.  Hope this clears it up.

Comment: This is very bad coding style. On every error the query will silently fail! From the docs:
`IGNORE`
When an applicable constraint violation occurs, the IGNORE resolution algorithm skips the one row that contains the constraint violation and continues processing subsequent rows of the SQL statement as if nothing went wrong. Other rows before and after the row that contained the constraint violation are inserted or updated normally. No error is returned when the IGNORE conflict resolution algorithm is used.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r that is the point.  OP wanted to insert rows (Primary Keys) that did not already exist in the table.  OP does not want an error for every Primary Key violation.  This emulates the MS SQL code in the original question.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to ignore the insertion of existing value, there must be a Key field in your Table. Just create a table With Primary Key Field Like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TblUsers (UserId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, UserName varchar(100), ContactName varchar(100),Password varchar(100));
```

And Then Insert Or Replace / Insert Or Ignore Query on the Table Like:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO TblUsers (UserId, UserName, ContactName ,Password) VALUES('1','UserName','ContactName','Password');
```

It Will Not Let it Re-Enter The Existing Primary key Value... This Is how you can Check Whether a Value exists in the table or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set a Constraint on a Table with the KEY fields and set On Conflict "Ignore"

> When an applicable constraint violation occurs, the IGNORE resolution
>   algorithm skips the one row that contains the constraint violation and
>   continues processing subsequent rows of the SQL statement as if
>   nothing went wrong. Other rows before and after the row that contained
>   the constraint violation are inserted or updated normally. No error is
>   returned when the IGNORE conflict resolution algorithm is used.

[SQLite Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can do "NOT EXISTS" with math, inverting  EXISTS output:

```
SELECT (1-EXISTS(<Your_SELECT>));
```

Your_SELECT is: S`ELECT 1 FROM EVENTTYPE WHERE EventTypeName = 'ANI Received'`

If exists is 1  , 1-1 result is 0. If
exists is 0  , 1-0 result is 1