# Insert if not exists?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm prompting a user to add an item to an SQLiteDb. When they click add, I want to check if that item already exists... if it doesn't then I want to insert it.

I make the call

```
mDbHelper.createNote(inputLine.getText().toString().trim(), mTable[i]);
```

Which calls...

```
public long createNote(String value, String table) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(table, value);

        return mDb.insert(table, null, initialValues);
    }
```

Thats works but it doesn't check if the item already exists, so it still inserts duplicates. So I tried

```
return mDb.insertWithOnConflict(table, null, initialValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_FAIL);
```

However, it doesn't appear to recognize insertWIthOnConflict or SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_FAIL...

How can I get this to work?

Edit: it's 1 table, 2 rows. table name = note, rows = _id, note.

Comment: Have you declared your _id column as a primary key?

Comment: yes, primary key autoincrement

Comment: A **much** better way to do this is detailed in [How to do IF NOT EXISTS in SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/q/531035/808940)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such situation I perfrom such checking:

```
if (!checkRecordExist(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_1, KEY_2}, new String[] {value_1, value_2})) 
database.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, updateValues);
```

where

```
private boolean checkRecordExist(String tableName, String[] keys, String [] values) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        sb.append(keys[i])
            .append("=\"")
            .append(values[i])
            .append("\" ");
        if (i<keys.length-1) sb.append("AND ");
    }

    Cursor cursor = database.query(tableName, null, sb.toString(), null, null, null, null);
    boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
    cursor.close();
    return exists;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you have multiple users checking to see if a record exists simultaneously?

Comment: I have local database, so only one request may be done at time. You may perform that checking on record adding and return warning if dublicate is found.

Comment: -1 although this works it is very poor practice and should be avoided, a better solution can be found using `INSERT OR IGNORE`. [How to do IF NOT EXISTS in SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/q/531035/808940)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [REPLACE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_replace.html) command

Comment: That seems to function exactly like insert. I'm able to insert the same item multiple times still.

Comment: If this is true, you didn't properly define a primary key

Answer (score 0):

Add a Primary Key.  If you try to insert another row with the same key, the insert will fail.

Comment: How do I find out if another row has the same key though? No key is generated until a record has been inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a primary key that isn't set to auto-increment?  That might be why the REPLACE command isn't working

Comment: Do you mean instead of having 2 columns, _id, note. I should get rid of _id and set note text primary key?

Comment: What I mean is that if you're willing to generate the primary key yourself, then you don't need to use auto-increment and your REPLACE might then work.  Note that for the answer you accepted above, you are doing two database calls for every insert (a check and the actual insert) so it'll slow down your time inside the DB.  It also has a TOCTOU issue in that it's not atomic, so make sure you synchronize properly if you're running multiple threads against it