# error in getting a check on local database in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i have a local database.I want that if user has already entered a medicine name say a.Then again i went to edittext and typed a .It should not  add in the local database,How to do this

I tried to follow this link

[Insert if not exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638049/insert-if-not-exists)

can anyone guide me

Thanks
Tushar

Comment: give some code sample that you have tried

Comment: Not sure what you want help with. Inserting if the row does not exist is exactly what you want. Looking at the linked example it looks correct.

Comment: Why did you link didn't work? Seems like a good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way... It help you.

```
String sql = "select * from "
                + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE placeId = '" + placeId + "'"; 
        Cursor cursorinfo = null; 
        try {
            database = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            cursorinfo = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

if (cursorinfo.moveToFirst()) {
            try {
                ///Already Exist data..
            } finally {
                database.close();
                cursorinfo.close();
            }

        } else {
            database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            try {
                database.insert(TABLE_NAME, "", values);
            } finally {
                database.close();
                cursorinfo.close();
            }
        }
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check if your `Record` is already there in table or not, and You have followed a right answer, I dont know why you are not able to do that, this is all you have to do.

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(tableName, null, "mediName="+editTextValue, null, null, null, null); 
boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0); 
cursor.close(); 

if(!exists)
{
    database.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, updateValues); 
}
else
{
    // Record Already there.
}
```