# Android SQLite check if value exists

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SQLite Database and insert some data like this, but now I would like to check first if this value is already in the database and only if its not insert it. How I can do this?

```
myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(MY_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + MY_DB_TABLE + "(db_datum)" 
 +"VALUES ('"+datum.getText().toString()+"');");
```

Comment: Please edit the your question, the inteded behaviour is not clear "... only if its now ...". Do you mean "only if it's not"?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for an `IF NOT EXISTS` statement (that is, if a record doesn't exist then do something, in this case insert a record)? I'm a little confused myself. This may help: [IF NOT EXISTS SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531035/how-to-do-if-not-exists-in-sqlite).

Comment: Yes I'm looking for an "IF NOT EXISTS" statement but now I have problems to implement this in android. Where I have to set the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
 Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MY_DB_TABLE+ " WHERE " + FIELD + "= '" + VALUE + "'");
 if(c == null)
 {
 //doesn't exists therefore insert record.
 }
```

Comment: Does not handle concurrent operations, use this instead [How to do IF NOT EXISTS in SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531035/how-to-do-if-not-exists-in-sqlite)

Comment: I think you should use this if(c.getCount() == 0)
 { 
 //doesn't exists therefore insert record. 
 }