# IF NOT EXISTS in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can I check whether devID already exists and then do the insertion for the following query, if devID does not exist already:

```
INSERT  into profiles (devID,alert) VALUES ("ff",1) ;
```

PS: I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531035/how-to-do-if-not-exists-in-sqlite) solution in SO, but not sure how to modify the query I have based on that solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO profiles (devID, alert)
SELECT 'ff', 1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM profiles WHERE devID = 'ff');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO profiles (devID,alert) VALUES ("ff",1) ;
```

As described in the [`INSERT` syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html):

[image]

Comment: I cannot see the checking performed here for the duplication of 'ff'

Comment: @user1400538 You need to have a unique index on devID for this to work, it basically says "insert if it doesn't conflict with existing data/indexes, otherwise ignore".

Answer (score 1):

According to your link:

```
INSERT INTO profiles (devID,alert)
SELECT "ff", 1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM profiles WHERE devID ="ff");
```

Comment: This may insert multiple rows for a device if they have different `alert` values, afaict not quite correct.

Comment: you right - I didn't read the part of only if exists the Id, I thougth he want that all combination doesn't exists. Edited