# Sqlite operationalError: syntax for IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, python-2.7

I am getting a sql lite operational syntax error for this code:

```
def checkIn(uname, title):
   bookid = findBookID(title) #returns an int bookid given the title
   print bookid
   with libDB:
      checkCur = libDB.cursor()
      checkCur.execute(
         "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Checks WHERE Username =? AND bookID =?) INSERT INTO Checks VALUES(?,?)",
         (uname, bookid, uname, bookid))
      checkCur.close()
      mess = "OK::CHKIN::", uname, "::", title
      return mess
```

The error is:

```
  sqlite3.OperationalError: near "IF": syntax error
```

This is how I defined the table:

```
   with libDB:
     checkCur = libDB.cursor()
     checkCur.execute(
         "CREATE TABLE Checks(bookID INTEGER, Username TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(bookID) REFERENCES Books(bookID),FOREIGN KEY(Username) REFERENCES Users(Username))")
     checkCur.close()
```

My apologies if I am missing something simple. I looked over the code several times and search online and I don't see where the syntax error is. I compared my query to those I found online and it seems to match. The only thing I can think of that could be wrong is if my parameters are not correct but I tried altering them and I still can't get it to work.

Thank you in advance for any help.

-CJ

Comment: This looks like it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531035/how-to-do-if-not-exists-in-sqlite  I'd try to help but I know nothing about databases.

Comment: @CodyPiersall Thank you for your help but it did not work. I'm still getting a syntax error even after implementing the code in your link.

Comment: Sorry @cjuf, but I don't know anything about Sqlite or any other database systems.  Hopefully someone will come along who can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IF NOT EXISTS` is incompatible with sqlite. The insert statement you want is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Checks (bookID, Username)
  SELECT 7, 'Bob'  /* for example */
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Checks WHERE bookID = 7 and Username = 'Bob');
```

Note that `NOT EXISTS` is in the `WHERE` clause. This sort of insert statement is [compatible with sqlite](http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html). You can play with the [sql fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/cb7b5/1/0).

So in your Python function, try this instead:

```
insert_stmt = ("INSERT INTO Checks (bookID, Username) "  # note the space at end of string
                  "SELECT ?, ? "
                  "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Checks WHERE bookID = ? and Username = ?)")
checkCur.execute(insert_stmt, (bookid, uname) * 2)  # no need to repeat the bookid, uname combo twice; just multiply the tuple by 2
```